# Async function resulting in stack size exceeded using Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

So I have this method:

```
   async generatePP() {
      if (this.generatedhtml == null && this.generating === false) {
        console.log("generating html");
        this.loading = true;
        this.generating = true;
        const report = await window.eel.ProfilingReportTest()();
        console.log("generated");
        console.log(report);
        this.loading = false;
        this.updatePandasProfile(report)
        this.generating = false;
      } else {
        console.log("already generated or in progress");
      }
    }
```

Now when this method is called I get the following error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at _traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2121)
    at _traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2123)
    at _traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2123)
    at _traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2123)
    .
    .
    .
    at traverse (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2100)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4490)
    at Watcher.run (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4554)
    at Watcher.update (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4542)
    at Dep.notify (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:730)
    at Object.reactiveSetter [as generatedhtml] (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1055)
    at Store.updatePandasProfile (mutations.js?c559:64)
    at wrappedMutationHandler (vuex.esm.js?2f62:744)
    at commitIterator (vuex.esm.js?2f62:392)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (vuex.esm.js?2f62:391)
    at Store._withCommit (vuex.esm.js?2f62:526)
    at Store.commit (vuex.esm.js?2f62:390)
    at Store.boundCommit [as commit] (vuex.esm.js?2f62:335)
    at Object.local.commit (vuex.esm.js?2f62:696)
    at Store.updatePandasProfileAction (actions.js?dab0:62)
    at Array.wrappedActionHandler (vuex.esm.js?2f62:751)
    at Store.dispatch (vuex.esm.js?2f62:442)
    at Store.boundDispatch [as dispatch] (vuex.esm.js?2f62:332)
    at Store.local.dispatch (vuex.esm.js?2f62:679)
    at VueComponent.mappedAction (vuex.esm.js?2f62:964)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479)
    at Watcher.evaluate (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4584)
    at VueComponent.computedGetter [as updatePandasProfileAction] (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4836)
    at _callee$ (PandasProfiling.vue?7527:112)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:45)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:274)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:97)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?fa84:5)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?fa84:27)
```

And multiple more of similar lines of errors.

Now this function worked before when instead having this line:

`this.updatePandasProfile(report)`

I had simply this

`this.generatedhtml = report`

However I moved `generatedhtml` to vuex store and created getters and actions to assign that `report` value to the state variable:

`mutations.js`

```
  updatePandasProfile (state, html) {
    state.generatedhtml = html;
  },
```

`actions.js`

```
  updatePandasProfileAction(context, html) {
    context.commit('updatePandasProfile', html)
  }
```

`getters.js`

```
generatedhtml: state => state.generatedhtml
```

I'm using getter in that component where `generatePP()` method is called

Any idea why this might be happening?

EDIT:
I also want to add that this `report` variable is pretty big in size (around 4,6mb)- it is a genrated html file.

Comment: do you watch the changes that has been made to generatedhtml after using getter ?

Comment: Why do I need to watch for changes since getter is already `computed` itself?

Comment: can we chat from [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213924/asnyc-func-resulting-max-call-stack-exceeded), i have couple of questions.

Comment: The `_traverse` function is where Vue walks down through an object's properties adding reactivity. In theory a very deeply nested structure could overflow the call stack but it's unlikely. Just being a large object wouldn't be enough. It's difficult to know exactly what the problem is without having access to the `report` object. You might want to try stepping through in the debugger to see what properties cause the problem. If `report` is static and you don't want to modify its contents you should just pass it through `Object.freeze` and dodge the problem altogether.

Comment: @skirtle `report` is basically a whole static site generated by this library https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling . After being generated I place this html variable into an iframe and thats it. It works when having everything in one component but since it bloats the code I thought of componentizing this a bit. However after placing that html variable in Vuex I get errors like above.

Comment: if you move the logic to vuex, shouldn't the line "this.updatePandasProfile(report)" become "this.$store.dispatch("updatePandasProfileAction", report)" to dispatch the action ?

Comment: @NgocTuanLam I dont think it is causing the error, calling action this way is also correct.

Comment: What is the returned value of `window.eel.ProfilingReportTest`? Is it a callable function?

Comment: Anyways, this type of problem can rarely be solved by chatting about it. It's solved by debugging (pausing script execution and inspecting). Which is impossible without a [mcve]. Besides, a reproducible example could give the ability to test with larger/smaller payloads and see if/when payload size breaks it. While setting a bounty does give your question more attention, a reproducible example would give it an actual shot at getting an answer.

Comment: So I acutally recreated an example and in the codesandbox it is working. I'm kind of in awe though. https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-actions-example-9hd45?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: So you can exclude everything you've added to the fiddle from possible bug sources. Now you need to figure out what's different in what you have. :) The best thing you can do in these cases is create a new project and move stuff into it bit by bit. Until it breaks. Painstaking, but pays off (most times).